# Disabling Intel Turbo Boost in ubuntu

Tags: cpu

I'm new to Ubuntu and want to disable the turbo boost. I tried with `cpufreq` but i cant get it to work. is there any other way to do it.

In windows it was as easy as changing the CPU speed from 100 to 99.

Comment: what's your cpu model?

Comment: @Ron: it is Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz I got the information from the chat they moved to. I think it doesn't really matter, what matters is which scaling driver is being used. Currently (which is different than the past) it will default to intel_pstate if the processor supports it.

Comment: guys, i tried : sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave
and it says :
Setting cpu: 0 
Setting cpu: 1
So where to put which core to change ? :)

Comment: Regardless of which scaling driver you are using, turbo enabled or not is a global setting, one spot covers all CPUs. Myself, I only use primitive commands, never higher level level tools such as `cpupower`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To read the current state of the Turbo Boost, we need to install the msr-tools

```
sudo apt-get install msr-tools
```

To know if the Turbo Boost feature is disabled, run:

```
rdmsr -pi 0x1a0 -f 38:38

1=disabled
0=enabled
```

**Replace i with your cores number**

---

**NOte:**
If you get the following error:

```
rdmsr:open: No such file or directory
```

then load the “msr” module by the following command:

```
sudo modprobe msr
```

---

To disable the Turbo Boost feature, one can set the entire 0x1a0 MSR register to 0x4000850089, as in here:

```
wrmsr -pC 0x1a0 0x4000850089
```

**Where C refers to a particular core number**

ou can get those number by running

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor
```

then once you know your numbers you have to run the command above for each core. in your case numbers would be 0 & 1 so you have to do

```
wrmsr -p0 0x1a0 0x4000850089

wrmsr -p1 0x1a0 0x4000850089
```

[Solution stands for this blog](http://luisjdominguezp.tumblr.com/post/19610447111/disabling-turbo-boost-in-linux)

---

From http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2014/11/a-script-to-turn-off-intel-cpu-turbo.html

**A script to disable/enable turbo boost**

The following script can be used to turn off/on turbo boost:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $(which rdmsr) ]]; then
    echo "msr-tools is not installed. Run 'sudo apt-get install msr-tools' to install it." >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -z $1 && $1 != "enable" && $1 != "disable" ]]; then
    echo "Invalid argument: $1" >&2
    echo ""
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) [disable|enable]"
    exit 1
fi

cores=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | awk '{print $3}')
for core in $cores; do
    if [[ $1 == "disable" ]]; then
        sudo wrmsr -p${core} 0x1a0 0x4000850089
    fi
    if [[ $1 == "enable" ]]; then
        sudo wrmsr -p${core} 0x1a0 0x850089
    fi
    state=$(sudo rdmsr -p${core} 0x1a0 -f 38:38)
    if [[ $state -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "core ${core}: disabled"
    else
        echo "core ${core}: enabled"
    fi
done
```

save this to a file called `turbo-boost.sh`

Usage:
You can copy the above script and save it into a file named turbo-boost then set it to be executable:

```
sudo chmod +x turbo-boost.sh
```

you can then use it to disable/enable turbo boost:

```
./turbo-boost.sh disable
./turbo-boost.sh enable
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23486/discussion-on-answer-by-new-user-disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu).

Comment: `$ rdmsr -pi 0x1a0 -f 38:38` gives me just a list of options to use with the command. e.g.: `Usage: rdmsr [options] regno
  --help         -h  Print this help
  --version      -V  Print current version ....` Is the above syntax outdated/ not applicable in a general way?

Comment: I get some missing files here: 

`wrmsr: open: No such file or directory
rdmsr: open: No such file or directory
core 0: enabled
wrmsr: open: No such file or directory
rdmsr: open: No such file or directory
core 1: enabled`

Comment: try `sudo rdmsr 0x1a0 -f 38:38`

Comment: Is it normal that I can't switch turbo boost for individual cores? It's either on for all, or off for all.

Comment: To set all cores at once, no need for a script: wrmsr has --all/-a switch: wrmsr -a 0x1a0 0x4000850089

Answer (score 66):

If your system is using the intel_pstate frequency scaling driver:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
intel_pstate
intel_pstate
intel_pstate
intel_pstate
intel_pstate
intel_pstate
intel_pstate
intel_pstate
```

Then you can inquire as to the turbo enabled or disabled status:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
0
```

Where 0 means turbo is enabled and 1 means it is disabled.
And you can change it by writting (as sudo) to the same location.

```
$ echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
1
```

I never remember the location or how to do the `tee' thing properly, so I prefer scripts to be run as sudo:

```
$ cat set_cpu_turbo_off
#! /bin/bash
echo "1" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo

$ cat set_cpu_turbo_on
#! /bin/bash
echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

Comment: If you have problems with permissions, try `sudo echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`

Comment: Can this be set permanently, to stay after reboot?

Comment: @Alexey : If you want it to be permanent, then i would suggest to do it in the BIOS instead. Otherwise make the above `set_cpu_turbo_off` script to run during startup.

Comment: @Cirelli94 - even so: `sudo echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
1
tee: /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo: Operation not permitted`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/876903/47206

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't have any effect for me in Ubuntu Server 14. `sudo wrmsr --all 0x1a0 0x4000850089` does the trick.

Comment: @sudo: Yep - same here on an Intel(R) Xeon(R) E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz. Can anyone explain the difference?

Comment: @spawn : bit 38 is the one that matters here, and is defined as turbo disable for "Intel® Xeon Phi™ Processors". Are you saying that when you read that register, after disabling turbo as per the answer, it still reads as zero? Seems to me that might be a bug. However, the docs says that some of these things are "shared" in Xeon processors, so not sure. If there is a bug, well its an old one.

Answer (score 4):

You can try setting `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost` value to 0.

```
echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost
```

Comment: it says no such file or directory

Comment: @Ron I recommend expanding this answer with an explanation of how to do that.

Comment: I agree with the comment from Eliah. It is a correct answer if the frequency scaling driver is acpi-cpufreq.

Comment: why the use of tee here?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Because you need root permission to write to this file and a normal pipe would only execute echo as root, but attempt the write as the current user. Therefore we need tee, which will write with its current user.

Answer (score -1):

In my case this works:

```
echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

Comment: The same command as in https://askubuntu.com/a/620114/.

Comment: This should be `echo 1` as in the accepted answer.