# Enabling/Disabling turbo boost 16.04

Tags: turbo-boost

I have searched all the posts here on ask ubuntu on how to do this and can't seem to figure it out still. What is the best way to disable and enable turbo boost? My fans are running quite loud on my x220 so I'd like to disable it. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on which CPU frequency scaling driver you are using. `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`

Comment: If intel_pstate, then see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/619875/disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu/620114#620114).

Comment: @DougSmythies - What that says is: use `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` to see if `intel_pstate`.  In my case yes. Then,  `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo` to see the status of turbo boost (0 means off, 1 means on). Mine is on. But then, to disable it should be `echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`, but what I get is `1
tee: /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo: Operation not permitted`. `sudo` before that as indicated in comment gives the same.

Comment: @cipricus : No, 1 means turbo disabled and 0 means turbo enabled. In your case it is disabled in the BIOS and therefore you can not change it. see also (your question) [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/876903/cannot-change-intel-turbo-boost-sys-devices-system-cpu-intel-pstate-no-turbo).