# How to enable CPU Turbo-Boost in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, cpufreq, boost, frequency, turbo-boost

I'm having server with 9700K and want to enable turbo-boost to get 4.9 GHz.

I've installed cpufrequtils and set performance mode.

Via 'cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq' I'm getting 3.6 GHz.

Using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yeah, sorry...Maybe there is other options?

Comment: 1 => means disabled. But i can't change it. Shows me an error like `tee: /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo: Operation not permitted
`

Comment: ah. then that is it See the answer.

Comment: Solved by this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/619875/disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 18.04.3 is not released.

Answer (score 3):

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

needs to show a `0`.  To make it `0` do ...

```
sudo -i
echo "0" | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
exit
```

- Assuming you have an Intel as it is called Intel Turbo Boost
- If you get a "Operation not permitted" it means you have turbo disabled in BIOS (source https://askubuntu.com/a/876998/15811 ) (and [intel pstate source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8fe28cb58bcb235034b64cbbb7550a8a43fd88be/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c#L999) and the [text explaining](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8fe28cb58bcb235034b64cbbb7550a8a43fd88be/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c#L176) it).

Comment: http://prntscr.com/op22bt still doesn't allow =(.

Comment: Does the whole directory exist? (or maybe do a `locate intel_pstate` and see where it is)

Comment: Basically yeah, http://prntscr.com/op2516 if i'm right, don't see any troubles, hehe). Btw, thank you for your time!

Comment: AH! you have turbo disabled in BIOS

Comment: In this case, what should i do? Ask provider to enable it in BIOS?

Comment: Eh you don't own it? If this is a cloud you probably can not enable it (you then need to upscale your instance = pay more ;) ).

Comment: Its serve from NFOrce, so yeah, im just paying for it each month.

Comment: Got an answer from their support `yes in the bios is disabled due to incompatibility with mother board. We can't enable it because system will not boot`. So in this case i'm not enable it?

Comment: Nope. Sorry. You can not override a bios setting from inside the OS.

Comment: Basically i've solved it via https://askubuntu.com/questions/619875/disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu

Comment: I get the following error `abhayp@abhayp:~$ sudo -i
root@abhayp:~# echo "0" | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
0
tee: /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo: Operation not permitted
root@abhayp:~# exit
logout
`