# cpupower with Intel® Core™ i7-8750H

Tags: drivers, dell, cpu

I have the Dell XPS 9570, I was using the `intel_pstate` driver to control the CPU frequency. But recently I have decided to disable it because there were problems when running on power - all of the 12 cores were running at 4GHz constantly and the fan was running non-stop. Running on battery was perfect. So I disabled the `intel_pstate`.

But now the CPU can only go to 2.20 GHz. Can I somehow modify the max frequency of the governor?

Comment: It sounds as though tubo is disabled. If you have disabled the intel-pstate CPU frequency scaling driver, then by default it should be using the acpi-cpufreq CPU frequency scaling driver, check via `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`. Does the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619875/disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu) help (in your case you would write a 1 to the location)?

Comment: the scaling driver is acpi-cpufreq

Comment: ```$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost
1
``` this means turbo is enabled, right? 

I am not sure what this has to do with turbo - should this not be only about mapping the pstate to frequencies?

Comment: Yes, i think that means that turbo is enabled. The relationship between turbo enabled/disabled and the maximum CPU frequencies is 4.1GHz is the max when turbo is enabled (depending on how many cores are running, as opposed to deep idle, at the same time) and 2.2 GHz is the max when turbo is disabled.

Comment: mhmm, so turbo is enabled but the governor does not know it can use it. Can I manually force it to use it?

Comment: Under a load such that you think the CPU frequency should be maximum, do: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/*` or if all CPUs are similar just `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/*` will do. Edit your question, adding the results.

Comment: scaling_max_freq:2201000 - i dont think it is aware it can go to 4GH?

Comment: Here is a dump from /sys/devices/cpu/cpufreq/policy: https://gist.github.com/Visgean/0daf39c86a22060128b6a6eccc34bc24

Comment: 2201000 is the acpi-cpufreq way of saying nominal (2.2GHz) plus turbo range (indicated by the 01 part). So, everything is fine.