# Disabling AMD's equivalent (on a Zen-1 Epyc) of Intel's "turbo boost" at runtime?

Tags: cpu, amd-processor, cpufreq, benchmarks, turbo-boost

This may be a terminology problem at my end and a duplicate: On Intel CPUs, I can relatively easy [disable turbo boost](https://askubuntu.com/q/619875/774859) at runtime by running something like

```bsh
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

The CPU then runs at its base clock without "turboing up". The nice thing is that I do not need to change BIOS/(U)EFI settings for that.

What would be the equivalent (in terms of both terminology and commands) on AMD CPUs, specifically on a Zen-1 Epyc?

*I am trying to run the CPU at constant (low) speed for consistent benchmark results. I am trying to compare different software implementations of algorithms.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, AMD processors use the acpi-cpufreq CPU frequency scaling driver.
Check via:

```
grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_driver
```

For that driver, to disable turbo boost, do:

```
echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost
```

Comment: And how to disable it again?

Comment: Is a reboot necessary?

Comment: @ThomasRS : No, the setting will be lost through a re-boot. `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost` to reverse the setting.

Comment: the double quotes around the zero are not needed

Comment: I am using EPYC 7543 on Ubuntu 22, and it does not have this file, and msr-tools do not work as well. Can someone help me?

Comment: @1a1a11a : Things have changed that answer was written. You might find that the newer amd-pstate CPU frequency driver is now the default. I don't know that there is an equivalent boost (turbo-core) disable for that driver (not sure).

Answer (score 0):

To make a persistent change, this command needs to be run by sudo on reboot. One way to do this is to append the setting to the crontab config file:

Edit crontab setting as admin:

`sudo crontab -e`

and append the command at the end of the config file:

`@reboot echo "0" | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost`

Moreover, if you are using gnome, you can check this awesome extension [Frequency Boost Switch](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4792/frequency-boost-switch/) to toggle the setting using GUI.