# How to underclock a CPU

Tags: cpu, overclocking

I am trying to find a solution to my laptop constantly overheating.
One thing I saw is that when idle my CPU does almost nothing (utilization is around 1%),
but the temperature is as high as 70*C.

My CPU is AMD Ryzen 5 3500U.

cpupower shows me following info:

```
# cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 1.40 GHz - 2.10 GHz
  available frequency steps:  2.10 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 2.10 GHz.
                  The governor "schedutil" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 1.40 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no
    Boost States: 0
    Total States: 3
    Pstate-P0:  2100MHz
    Pstate-P1:  1700MHz
    Pstate-P2:  1400MHz
```

So I know I can switch to constant 1400 MHz, but that is not my goal.
I would like to underclock my CPU dropping its minimum frequency from 1.4GHz to eg. 700MHz

How can I do it, and what tools should I use for that?

Also cpupower shows that maximum allowed frequency is 2.1GHz,
but the CPU spec shows its boost value to be 3.7GHz.
How can I set that as my maximum frequency?

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294142/disabling-amds-equivalent-on-a-zen-1-epyc-of-intels-turbo-boost-at-runtime/1294406#1294406) should be good enough for your needs. The heat might also be from elsewhere, like graphics, or just poor ventilation.

Comment: are you sure that is too hot, check the specs. my 2500U is rated to 95C  https://askgeek.io/en/cpus/AMD/Ryzen-5-2500U  .. it was normally 80C but the latest updates have brought it down to 60C. nice and renice can target specific processes.

Comment: It is, remember 70*C is the value when idle. When on full load it keeps thermal throttling constantly staying above 90*C.