# How to disable frequency boost and hyperthreading

Tags: drivers, cpu

I'm trying to disable both hyperthreading and frequency boost to benchmark some code. Because I cant find anything about this on the BIOS, I ran `lscpu` to get some information about the CPU (AMD Ryzen 7 4700U) and I get this information

```
CPU(s):                  8
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Vendor ID:               AuthenticAMD
  Model name:            AMD Ryzen 7 4700U with Radeon Graphics
    CPU family:          23
    Model:               96
    Thread(s) per core:  1
    Core(s) per socket:  8
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            1
    Frequency boost:     enabled
    CPU max MHz:         2000,0000
    CPU min MHz:         1400,0000
```

Because there is only 1 thread per core, I'm assuming my CPU does not support hyperthreading (I'm not sure about this).

To disable frequency boost, I have tried running this command, which as far as I understand should clock the CPU to the highest frequency

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor performance
```

but when I run `lscpu` I still get

```
Frequency boost:     enabled
```

Does anyone know the correct way to disable both hyperthreading and frequency boost (without using the BIOS because I can't find anything about this there)

**EDIT** The CPU frequency scaling driver is

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
```

Comment: The answer might depend on which CPU frequency scaling driver you are using. Do: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and edit your answer to include the information. Yes, it seems you do not have hyperthreading.

Comment: Check out this thread in superuser
https://superuser.com/questions/454101/is-there-a-way-to-disable-intel-speedstep-steppings-on-an-ubuntu-server-using-a

Comment: @DougSmythies Edited the questions. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Okay, for the acpi-cpufreq CPU frequency scaling driver do: `echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost`. see also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294142/disabling-amds-equivalent-on-a-zen-1-epyc-of-intels-turbo-boost-at-runtime/1294406#1294406).

Comment: @DougSmythies It worked, thanks!